# Backup Wifi SSID and password on SGSII

Tags: wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-s-2, backup, factory-reset

I updated my sgs2 [I9100] to JB, I want it to format or wipe that clean and stable install. I can backup everything except wifi keys. I guess kies seems have it, but it was not work before.

How can I export or backup them without rooting? Then which way should I follow to format-wipe-resetfactroy like as a brandnew phone?

Answer (score 1):

On newer versions of Android, WiFi settings are backed up along with your Google account (If you've enabled it in `Settings -> Backup & reset -> Back up my data`), and restored when you link your Google account back to your wiped or new device.

Note that in my personal experience, the Google backup feature is a bit flaky, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. On new devices it usually works, but when wiping/installing ROMs it may fail.

Comment: I have forgotten to say I do not want to share wi-fi and etc.. parsonal stuff with google and as mach as I understand it may not work properly anyway.
Is there any working solution without rooting nor google?
Or this result is Google want to collect everything?

Answer (score 0):

Use Titanium Backup PRO to do so.

Start the app. Tap MENU in the top right corner. Scroll down to the SPECIAL BACKUP / RESTORE section and choose BACKUP DATA TO XML

There - choose Wi-Fi Access Points.

To Restore, choose RESTORE DATA from XML.

Comment: Can I do it without root with Titanium Backup PRO?

Comment: There are apps other than TiBP that allow a user to backup/restore the WiFi access point details. Unfortunately, ALL of them need ROOT access. May I ask why you opted for an Android device when you're unwilling to use a Google account (perhaps even a non-essential throwaway Google ID just for backup purposes) ?

Comment: http://sadevil.org/blog/2012/10/23/copying-over-your-wifi-access-points-on-android/ shows how to perform a backup/move manually using ADB but that too depends on elevated privileges as evidenced by the use of 'su'.